# How to change time zone(TZ=UTC) output in execl() function.

Tags: c, linux, fork, system, execl

I am using running one binary eg. 'ls -la' in my c code with **execl()** function and reading return status of child process. **execl("/bin/ls", "ls", "-la", NULL);** and receiving child status by **waitpid(pid, &status, 0 );** function. But i need my out put in different time zone like **TZ=UTC**. 
So like to use 'ls -la' as 'TZ=UTC ls -la'. So is it possible to pass time zone argument with execl() function. Or is there any way to get the output in specific time zone. 
Looking for c code.

Comment: "Looking for c code." is nice as the tag is C, yet rather than post what you have tried, you described it.  Better and more clear to post compilable  code you have attempted.  It adds value to the details of what you are attempting.

Comment: Use `execle` and provide an environment with `TZ` set to `UTC`.

Answer (score 1):

For this simple case, the easiest solution is to use [`setenv`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/setenv.3.html) to modify the value of the  `TZ` environment variable just before calling `execl`. (Presumably you `fork()` before the call to `execl`; the `setenv` should be called after the `fork()` only in the child process, so that it doesn't modify the parent's environment.)

You could create an entire environment list and then pass it to `execle`. But that's a lot of work for little benefit. You might want to do that if you were calling a setuid executable, or if you wanted to add a lot of environment variables, or if your C library doesn't have `setenv`. But in normal cases, the single `setenv` call is just fine.